# Tooltip CSS is forcing my text to run vertically

Tags: css

Please read my profile before proceeding. Anyone who doesn't keep the critique to only the code itself will be disregarded. Okay? Okay.

I'm trying to do tooltips to my navigation header, using [the code on this page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp). The bottom tooltip, specifically.

I've snagged out the relevant parts of code from my own CSS and webpage to tool around with in their Try It Editor to get it working, and I've been cussing at this since last week and this is the furthest I've gotten to making it work, and even that came with some sacrifices in design I'm not sure how to fix. I will admit that tooltips like this are a very new area for me, and I'm trying to learn a new thing, and it's making me give it a very salty side-eye. So pointers to where I'm going wrong and what I need to be doing to correct it are what I'm looking for. Links to any sites that explain this better would also be tremendously appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url(http://www.metathriving.com/img/index2bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #72809F;
}

/* Header */

#header {
width: 960px;
height: 160px;
margin: 0px auto;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/* Boy Without A Fairy */

#navi {
float: left;
width: 900px;
height: 55px;
}

#navi ul li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

#navi a {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 45px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
color: #578fa8;
}

#navi a:hover {
color: #9dd0ed;
}

#navi a.active {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.tooltip {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
visibility: hidden;
width: 120px;
background-color: #c0c0c0;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 5px 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 150%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
visibility: visible;
}

</style>
<body>

<div id="header">

<!-- Hey! Listen! -->

<div id="navi">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index2.html"><span style="color:#c0c0c0; font-weight: bold;">Just Another<br>Brick in<br>the Wall</span></a></li>
        <li><div class="tooltip"><a href="about.html">Weary Eyes Still<br>Stray to the<br>Horizon  <span class="tooltiptext">More About Me</a></span><div></li>
        <li><a href="http://thirdlaw.metathriving.com/"><span style="font-style: italic;">A Heavenly Ride<br>Through<br>Our Silence</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="ancestors.html"><span style="font-style: italic;">A Thousand<br>Miles of<br>Moonlight Later</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="social"><span style="font-style: italic;">Trade Your Heroes<br>For Ghosts</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="health"><span style="font-style: italic;">If You Can Hear<br>This Whispering<br>You Are Dying</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="dignityeol.html"><span style="font-style: italic;">I'll See You On<br>the Dark Side<br>of the Moon</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="links.html"><span style="font-style: italic;">Frontiers Shift<br>Like<br>Desert Sands</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/Teatime_Check"><span style="font-style: italic;">You Are Only<br>Coming Through<br>In Waves</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a screencap of what that code renders in the w3schools.com Tryit Editor panel. (Ignore the font colors and the fact it's not easy to see in some spots because of text + background. the font will be tweaked when I have the layout done, I change up font colors as I work to make sure things are working and to single out stuff. And the full code does give a solid background under the text for better legibility.)

[Screencap of what the code makes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1iG1.png)

As you can see, it line breaks. Where it does, the tool tip works. But it's not supposed to move the rest of it to a new line. At least, I don't want it to do that. I'm not sure where it's going off the rails here. Like I said, this is a new trick I'm trying to learn and I'm stumped, after a week of working, research, and several books studying. It's right in front of me, and it's gotta be bloody obvious, but what IS it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

There were a few tags in the tooltip incorrectly wrapped. Namely, `<a></span></a></span>`. I corrected this.

Then, the tooltip is causing the break you don't want. Add a `float: left;` to the `.tooltip` class.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: url(http://www.metathriving.com/img/index2bg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #72809F;
}
/* Header */

#header {
  width: 960px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* Boy Without A Fairy */

#navi {
  float: left;
  width: 900px;
  height: 55px;
}
#navi ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
}
#navi a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #578fa8;
}
#navi a:hover {
  color: #9dd0ed;
}
#navi a.active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  float: left;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style> <body> <div id="header"> <!-- Hey! Listen! -->
```

```html
<div id="navi">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index2.html"><span style="color:#c0c0c0; font-weight: bold;">Just Another<br>Brick in<br>the Wall</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"><a href="about.html">Weary Eyes Still<br>Stray to the<br>Horizon  <span class="tooltiptext">More About Me
        </span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://thirdlaw.metathriving.com/"><span style="font-style: italic;">A Heavenly Ride<br>Through<br>Our Silence</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="ancestors.html"><span style="font-style: italic;">A Thousand<br>Miles of<br>Moonlight Later</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="social"><span style="font-style: italic;">Trade Your Heroes<br>For Ghosts</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="health"><span style="font-style: italic;">If You Can Hear<br>This Whispering<br>You Are Dying</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="dignityeol.html"><span style="font-style: italic;">I'll See You On<br>the Dark Side<br>of the Moon</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="links.html"><span style="font-style: italic;">Frontiers Shift<br>Like<br>Desert Sands</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/Teatime_Check"><span style="font-style: italic;">You Are Only<br>Coming Through<br>In Waves</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying to thank you while avoiding plain thanks. I claim luser end fail with the `</a></span></a></span>` bit. Was an artifact from a final attempt to figure out how to work things. Thought I caught and changed them all.

For some reason, I've had a lot of problems grokking the float command. Just when I think I almost understand it, I find myself staring blankly and going "...huh?" Between self-taught and chemo brain...

Thank you for explaining that. Narrowing down the issue so I know where to focus future troubleshooting is the help I needed.

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept the solution if it worked for you.

Comment: Oh! The checkmark. I was looking for something in words. Knowing for sure there WAS something to find... :) FWIW, here's the still-under-construction you helped fix if curious. metathriving.com/index2.html Hopefully from here on out I'll be able to finish building on my own.